# Facing issue the usage of Data Annotations in .Net 6

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, validation, c#-3.0

**Hi, I'm using .Net 6 & visual studio 2022 community.

My Model validations through Data Annotations are working for all HTML tags, i want to use only for some fields..**

**Code:**

```
public class Student
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Display(Name="Student Name")]
        [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Required(ErrorMessage = "Please provide a value for Name field")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Email{ get; set; }
        public string Department{ get; set; }
    }
}
```

**HTML:
**I'm using Tag helpers to render HTML code.****

```
@model MiddleWareComponents.Models.Student

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Student";
}

<form asp-controller="home" asp-action="student" method="post" class="mt-3">

    <div class="form-group row">
        <label asp-for="@Model.Name" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"></label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input asp-for="@Model.Name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
            <span asp-validation-for="@Model.Name" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>

 <div class="form-group row">
        <label asp-for="@Model.Department" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"></label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input asp-for="@Model.Department" class="form-control" placeholder="department">
            
        </div>
    </div>

 <div class="form-group row">
        <label asp-for="@Model.Email" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"></label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input asp-for="@Model.Email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
        
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>



<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.3/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/3.2.12/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
```

**When we run the code, all html fields are required necessary to fill up , otherwise these fields are giving error and submit button not going to server. But there is only Name field is Required & mentioned in the model. **

**Please give me a solution, how i can restrict some of the fields required to fill up , & some fields are not required. Thanks**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accroding to your decription,I think you could check if you have referred the js files and if the js files are in the correct order,you could check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-6.0#client-side-validation) related for more details:

```
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.3/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/3.2.12/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks,issue is resolved,  i was missing only these script files..

Answer (score 0):

If your model state is not valid you want to return the view with the view-model instead of the empty string:

```
[HttpPost]
public string Student(Student student)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
       return RedirectToAction("yourAction", "yourController");
    }
    else
    {
        return View(student);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can find additional information about form validation at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/validation?view=aspnetcore-6.0